# Unique constraint violation found after upgrading to Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, ssh, magento2.3.3

I just recently upgraded from `Magento 2.3` to `Magento 2.3.3` and whenever I'm trying to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` SSH command it just stick on Unique constraint violation found. Any idea how do I fix this ?

Error after running the `php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade` SSH command:

```
    In AbstractDb.php line 427:

  Unique constraint violation found  


In Mysql.php line 593:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '  
  order-0' for key 'SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID', query was:  
   INSERT INTO `mg_sales_sequence_meta` (`entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequ  
  ence_table`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)                                            


In Mysql.php line 110:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '  
  order-0' for key 'SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID', query was:  
   INSERT INTO `mg_sales_sequence_meta` (`entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequ  
  ence_table`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)                                            


In Mysql.php line 91:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '  
  order-0' for key 'SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID'              


setup:db-data:upgrade [--magento-init-params MAGENTO-INIT-PARAMS]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**"Running schema recurring.Unique constraint violation found"** this occurs if there is **duplicate entry in any table of project db** and high probability to occur this problem is when you export db and then import,if db is not export completely or correctly.

so the solution is just export db again correctly and import

**and if you created tables then define at least one field as unique value in each table**

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the :

```
**order-0
Invoice-0
creditmemo-0
Shipment-0
wrlcw_trx-0
Order-1
Invoice-1
Creditmemo-1
Shipment-1
wrlcw_trx-1**
```

From **mg_sales_sequence_meta**  and it fixed the error for me.

[image]

Comment: you mean delete all records will resolve this? Please help me